# Extending using C# generics?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I want to create an extendable nested structure and it seems like I should be able to do this using generics, though I may not be using them "properly".

I want to be able to create child classes from GroupType and/or OptionType. The problem is that I can't perform the `new` operation on the generic types even though I specified they could only be of a certain base type.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

```
public class AllInfo<GroupType, OptionType> 
    where GroupType: GroupBase<OptionType>
    where OptionType: OptionBase
{
    public List<string> Names { set; get; }
    public List<GroupType> Groups { set; get; }

    public AllInfo()
    {
        DataSet ds = DatabaseRetreival();
        this.Groups.add(new GroupType(ds["Name"], ds["Type"]));
    }

}

public class GroupBase<OptionType> 
    where OptionType: OptionBase
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Type { set; get; }
    public List<OptionType> Options { set; get; }

    public GroupBase(string name, string type)
    {
         this.Name = name;
         this.Type = type;

         DataSet ds = DatabaseRetreival(this.Type);
         this.Options.Add(new OptionType(ds["Name"]));
    }
}

public class OptionBase
{
    public string Name { set; get; }

    public OptionBase(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify which constructors a generic class should have. The constructors are not inherited, so even if the base class that you specified has that constructor, a class that derives from it doesn't have to have that constructor.

The only constructor that you can require is the parameterless constructor:

```
where GroupType: GroupBase<OptionType>, new()
```

As that only let's you use the parameterless constructor, you would also use a virtual method for putting the data in the object, for example:

```
GroupType group = new GroupType();
group.Init(ds["Name"], ds["Type"]);
this.Groups.add(group);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify the classes must have a default constructor.

```
where GroupType: GroupBase<OptionType>, new()
```

View [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx) and jump down to the section titled **Generic Constraints**.

Comment: That doesn't help, as he doesn't use the parameterless constructor.

Comment: Ah, there is no constraint for multiple-parameter constructors though there is an article I ran across using lambdas to which might be used. http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2007/11/an-alternative-to-the-c-generic-new-constraint/

Comment: Serious performance implications of the new() constraint http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zelmalki/archive/2008/12/13/creating-objects-using-generic-new-constraint.aspx

@Erik +1 for lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot allow that, because it cannot guarantee that the `OptionType` has a constructor with the right signature. But you can pass a factory function instead of invoking the constructor directly:

```
public class Foo<T> 
{
    private List<T> myObjects;

    public Foo(Func<string, T> factory))
    {
        myObjects = new List<T>();
        foreach (string s in GetDataStrings())
            myObjects.Add(factory(s));
    }
}
```

So if you have a `Bar` class with a constructor taking a string, you do this:

```
Func<string,Bar> barFactory = x => new Bar(x);
var foo = new Foo<Bar>(barFactory);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is foundationally based in very high amounts of class coupling that you are trying to mitigate with inheritance/generics. I suggest you re-examine why you feel this is necessary. This quest will eventually lead you to interfaces, service-based programming, and IoCs like Ninject or Castle Windsor.

However, if you want a quick fix that further increases code complexity (because you don't have non-complex options here aside from changing your coding philosophy), **use an abstract/virtual method**, maybe call it Bind(), **instead of constructors.**

[bolded for tl;dr]